# jQueryUI does not work

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I'm a relatively inexperienced coder but this relatively 'simple' issue has me stumped. I created a new ASP MVC project in VS 2013 and added jquery and jqueryUI via Nuget. I'm trying to display a simple jquery modal and it will simply not load - the modal div is displayed as part of the parent page. In fact, any jqueryUI element (such as a datepicker) will produce an error such as :
    Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

I ran the following code to check whether jquery and jqueryUI are loaded, and both apparently are:

```
if (window.jQuery) {
alert("jQueryloaded");
}

if (typeof jQuery.ui != 'undefined') {
alert("UI Loaded");
}
```

Here is my code for a datepicker element:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/MySurveys.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

I tried removing the include jquery and jqueryUI lines to see if the lines are possibly loaded twice, and they are not, as removal produced errors stating that jquery cannot be found.

I also tried referencing the libraries directly form jquery.com but no difference.

Note: MySurvey.js just contains some innocuous knockoutJS code that hasn't given me any issues in the past.

Comment: jQuery may be loaded...but is the `$` shortcut assigned to it? What happens if you `alert(window.$);`?

Comment: Just add the reference <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> in your code..

Comment: If I run alert(window.$) then I get the following output: function ( selector, context ) { // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced' return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery ); }

Comment: (strikethrough)What an interesting output!(/strikethrough)

Comment: Looks like jQuery is loaded. Hmm. By the way @rajeeshmenoth that wouldn't work as `//` loads using the same protocol, and it would appear to be that @PaulP is opening the file via `file://`.

Comment: provide  jsfiddle link, that would be helpful for others to identify the issue.

Comment: Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scf4qq3L/